# How to prove this integral vanish?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need to prove that $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^2-9}{\cosh z} $$ vanishes, where this integral is around a circle of radius of module one centered at the origin.

I thought that it could be possible to use some trick to end in the Riemann-Cauchy theorem, but I am not sure what trick to use. So I suppose that maybe there was a antiderivative function, which would make the integral vanish too.

But trying to find an antiderivative didn't work, so my ideas ended. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:-
Since the given function is analytic in given domain and have continous derivative, from Cauchy integral theorem.
$$\oint_C f(z) dz =0$$
along every simole smooth, closed curve $C$ contained in $D$.
Let $$f(z) = \frac{z^2-9}{coshz}$$

As  $coshz$ will become *zero* at $z = \frac{\iota \pi (2n+1)}{2}$
And the given domain $|z|$ doesn't contain any points where $f(z)$ is not analytic.

Hence

The integral $$\int_{|z|} \frac{z^2-9}{coshz} dz = 0$$

Comment: Hi, thank you. I thought that, but for example: the integral of tanz around the same point is zero isn't? With the same pah. This path, but, include z=0. So i just thought that the fact that include or not z=0 didn't matter. So what's the difference between tanz and this function, for example?

Comment: You have to include every point in the closed curve to test the function to be analytic. $tanz$ can be written as $\frac{sinz}{cosz}$, $tanz$ is not analytic at $z = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$ , you have to consider suppose $cotz$ that is not analytic at $z=0$ that is contained in $|z|=1$

Comment: @Lac please accept the answet if you find it helpfull